# Updating parent's state from Routed component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

We are using react, react-redux, and react-router. In one of my components, I am using the `<Route>` component from react-router to render one of my form components. Upon submitting the form and creating the event, I would like my parent component( the one that had the `<Route>` component in it) rerender so that my list of events will include the added event.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <PublicEvents events={state.public}/>
            <PrivateEvents events={state.private}/>
            <Route component={Form}>
        </div>
     )
 }
```

How would I go about updating those state properties so that it would rerender after Form is submitted? I tried have the parent component and the Form component connected to the store and used mapDispatchToProps, but not sure if I'm supposed to do that. My reducers do get the new events, but I don't think its updating my parent component's state.

Answer (score 2):

Does React Router allow you to pass arbitrary props through the `Route` component? A standard paradigm in React is to pass `onX` callbacks to children as props to handle state changes/events in the parent.

in the parent component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  onFormSubmit = () => {
    // update local state, here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <Route component={Form} onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and then in your `Form` component

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = (data) => {
    if (this.props.onSubmit) this.props.onSubmit(data)
    ...
  }
}
```

another option is to use a global state store like `redux` - the `Form` component would update the store, and the changes would be reflected in the parent "transparently" (by definition of how `redux` operates)

edit: They're suggesting the following to pass props through to children:

```
<Route render={(props) => <Form {...props} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>} />
```

per: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105

Comment: Not a weird approach. Render props is a pattern that is gaining traction in the React community. The withRouter HOC that comes with ReactRouter is implemented using a render prop. Passing props from the parent down is an specific use case that this solves. Here is a video that may convince you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcVAq3YFiuc

Comment: haha sorry, you're right. I was just being a little opinionated. my ideal approach would be transparently passing props through the `Route` component, but that has potential to cause prop name conflicts - I can see why they went with a render prop.

Comment: No sweat, like I said, it is still gaining traction. It is even in the official documentation now.

Comment: Thanks! The render prop worked for me. It would have been nice if I could have just used redux and dispatch an event instead of having to pass down an onX function.